# All pages from my site are showing a 404 error in the Google cache from search results

Tags: google-search-console, 404, soft-404

For the last 30 days, all internal pages of my website have been showing 404 error in the Google cache. When I click on 'Cached' on any page, it shows below error message:

> The requested URL `/search?q=cache:BbNXUt4kf1EJ:SITEURL+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl` was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

[image]

I tried to use the "Fetch as Google" feature from Google Search Console a couple of time, but no luck. It's still showing 404 error.

Comment: Same plugin installed on other sites, and it's working fine. 

Can't figure out what exactly is the issue, it been about a month, and Cached is still showing 404 error.

Comment: How old are these pages?   Have been live  for weeks, months, or years?

Comment: I have resumed the work on this site from about August month, although the website is about 1.6 yr old.

Thus pages are about 1+ month old and many of them are new pages.

Answer (score 1):

404 means the page does not currently have a cache to show.

There has been some cache reporting issues recently, due to the switch to mobile first indexing. Did you receive a notification that your site has gone mobile first?

Check in the Google Search Console for indexing issues. You can do a URL inspection on a specific URL without a public cache to see if it is indexed fine. That's what's more important.

Comment: It's still showing 404 error in cache version. 

There is no such error in Search Console.