# Google caching not complete

Tags: seo, google-search-console, fetch-as-google, google-cache

I have a web page where I had used the URL inspection tool to request Google to crawl it. The HTML code has for the meta tags as shown below:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="private">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name = "description" content = "blah blah blah">
```

In the Fetch as Google tool, I requested for the indexing and it doesn't show the result:

[image]

When I select the view cached page from he Google Search, it always redirects to the main page instead of the cached version. It directs to the cache page and stays there for a second before redirecting to the main page.

Snapshot of the cached version here:

[image]

However, there is no snapshot.

Updated with the Fetch and Render results:

[image]

And the fetching shows me the code of the page.

Please can you help?

Comment: There have been reported issues about Google not updating its cache lately or returning a `404` status code - see [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/116989/all-pages-from-my-site-are-showing-a-404-error-in-the-google-cache-from-search-r) related question.  If you've only recently used Fetch as Google, it may take much longer for it to appear, especially given those recent reports.

Comment: When Fetch as Google "didn't show the result", had you tried "Fetch and Render"?   Fetch and render should show you the page as Googlebot sees it.

Comment: Yes, Stephen. Tried both 'Fetch' and 'Fetch and Render'. Both of them were able to complete the operations. And I requested indexing and the status currently says "Indexing Requested".

Comment: You probably have code on the page that redirects if the address is not correct. You're page also takes a very long time to load, which is probably why you see blank caches. Does the fetch and render show any content?

Comment: Hi Tony, I dont think there is any redirects on address. The fetch and render shows the contents. Updated the question with the Fetch and render results. FYI - The indexing is still shown as requested.